# Having issue in explode function and path retrieval?How to use it properly

Tags: php, explode

In database multiple image name  is stored with comma separation and image is stored in upload folder.Now I want retrieve the data from db using explode function. what I have done so far,My page view source is returning this.I dont know where I went wrong. kindly guide me. In db the image stored like this. Lighthouse.jpg,Penguins.jpg,Tulips.jpg. I have used foreach in while loop.shall i want to use foreach or with the help of while loop itself we can retrieve the data

```
My page view source is returning this
<img src="upload/L"  />
<img src="upload/P"  />
<img src="upload/T"  />
 here is my php code
    <?php
    $sub=mysql_query("select iname from properties ps ");
    while($listnew=mysql_fetch_array($sub))
    {
    $res = explode(",", $listnew['iname']);
    foreach ($res as $item) {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo "upload/".$item['iname'];?>"  />
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: The explode() is returning a simple array - not an associative array. Try using for($x-0; $x<count($res); $x++) as see how that works

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this because u already have ur each image name in $item after exploding and then iterating through exploded array:

```
<img src="<?php echo "upload/".$item;?>"  />
```

Comment: You answr is correct, i try to tick the answer after I worked out, it says within 2 minutes u have tick  to the answer. I want to know  how to retrieve the data using while loop itself, i don't want to use foreach in while loop.  can you?

Comment: I don't see any harm in this if you are retrieving multiple rows from database or is it one

Comment: @ amit, I am waiting for your valuable answer.I will retrieving multiple rows based on product id, I mean id 50 has 4 image and id 51 has 3 image like  that.... I try to achieve like this. http://chlorophile.co.in/index.php/collection/men/linum-pro-459.html  ,u see in left side afte loading the page

Comment: @user3804431 do u retrieve one row from database or multiple rows ? In case of multiple you have to loop through all of them and if its just one then while will execute just once

Comment: can u tell me what plugin I have use to achieve like that in user side, now we have retrieved the data from db next , mouse arrow click and zooming option needed. i hope u understood. beacuse no thread was like this in stack overflow, if we both completed it is really useful to some one like me!

Comment: @user3804431 you can look into front end framework like  http://getbootstrap.com/ or http://materializecss.com/ which provides front end manipulation functionalities out of the box. Hope this solves ur problem and please accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: I accepted your answer but system is not accepting the tick mark. what plugin i want to download for this, bootstrap  is not required , i am comfortable in css, already i hosted the website, please see the link   http://jazzyvogue.in/home.php i want to know the jquery plugin . can you help me with your knowledge i already told no query was like this.

Comment: @user3804431 checkout this http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples if this is something u are looking for then download their plugin seems to be very easy

Comment: Thanks lot . This is what I have  expected